# Model with a read only, dependant attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a model that has two attributes: A `ast`-attribute (`jsonb`) that contains a complex data structure and a `compiled`-attribute (`string`) that can be recreated anytime from the `ast`-attribute.

As the compilation-process is possibly lengthy I would like to update the `compiled` attribute if the `ast`-attribute was changed. For this caching behavior I would go with a `before_save` callback and simply check whether `ast` has changed and then possibly start the compilation process.

As the `compiled`-attribute strictly depends on the `ast`-attribute there is no reason to ever set it directly. I was thinking to do this via explicitly overriding `compiled=` but maybe there is a more elegant way to do this? And how would I set the property myself from the callback in that case?

To me this feels like I am missing some functionality that Rails could have implemented already. So instead of re-inventing the wheel as described above I would prefer to do this the "Rails way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stay away from callbacks and do something like:

```
def ast=(value)
  super(value)
  self.send(:compiled=, from_ast(ast), force: true) # from_ast is meant to transform the data the way you need
end

def compiled=(value, force: false)
  super(value) if force
  # maybe raise if force is false?
end
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use callbacks?

Comment: I would say callbacks are a root of evil. They are hidden code, they most of the time end up crying for context becoming conditional and this is where we can go off rails. Plus we dont control their order and not really what happens if something goes wrong. I feel like it's much clearer to show your intent right away: "I want X to happen when I change Y value" => "override setter (or wrap everything in a service object) so it is straight forward"

Comment: I have tried to figure out the correct syntax for your snippet and it somehow escapes me. How do I call the `compiled=` method that you provide? The snippet seems to pass the `force` parameter to `from_ast`. You can find my attempt at https://bitbucket.org/snippets/marcusriemer/Le7ypA